# Where is the .Trash folder?

Tags: xdg

Using Ubuntu 11.10, I accidentally deleted a file that was approximately 700 MB. I tried to find it in the in following locations, but couldn't:

```
/home/user/.local/share
/home/user/ <-- there was no folder .Trash
/home/user/Desktop/ <-- there was no folder .Trash
```

So where did .Trash go in Ubuntu 11.10 onward? I use the Gnome environment.

Comment: I find `/home/user/.local/share` after installing `trash-cli` with `sudo apt-get install trash-cli`

Answer (score 284, accepted):

Your trash directory is most likely at:

```
/home/$USER/.local/share/Trash
```

If you deleted something as root (e.g. deleted a file using Nautilus invoked via `gksu`), it is at:

```
/root/.local/share/Trash
```

(In general, according to Freedesktop.org specifications<sup>[[1]](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/trash-spec/trashspec-1.0.html)[[2]](https://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html)</sup>, the "home trash" directory is at `$XDG_DATA_HOME/Trash`, and `$XDG_DATA_HOME` in turn defaults to `$HOME/.local/share`.)

To see `.local` in your home folder using the file manager, select `Show Hidden Files` from the `View` menu or just type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.

The `Trash` directory is first created when a user deletes a file. Within `Trash` there are three subdirectories:

- `files`, where the deleted files are stored until the trash is emptied
- `info`, which stores information on where the files once were and when they were deleted
- `expunged`, to which files are briefly moved when the trash is emptied (but may contain some owned by other users from directories you deleted).

Note that using the `rm` command in a terminal or the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> key combination in the file manager will permanently delete your file instead of moving it to the trash.

Comment: If using command line to `mv` something to the Trash, you may need to put it in `Trash/files/` rather than just `Trash/`.  The files did not appear in the Trash GUI until I did that.

Comment: Yes; I added some info to address this.

Comment: The locations still apply in 14.04

Comment: If you want to move file to `Trash` from command line, run: [`gvfs-trash filepath`](https://www.mankier.com/1/gvfs-trash).

Comment: An alternative to `gvfs-trash` is the `trash` command from the `trash-cli` package.

Comment: when i manually move the file to the trash/files folder and manully write the file.trashinfo file in the trash/info folder myself . It doesn't show the "restore from trash" option in the Trash . How to fix it ?

Comment: Why is `trash` in `/home/../.local/share` and not in `/home/user`?

Answer (score 52):

The trash folder is located at `.local/share/Trash` in your home directory.

Additionally, on other disk partitions or on removable media it will be a directory .Trash-*uid* where *uid* is the uid of the user who moved the item to the trash.

Comment: I cannot see this folder in my home directory. i am using ubuntu 14

Comment: @Vivek Files and directories whose names start with a dot (`.`) are hidden by default. In Nautilus, you can press CTRL+H to show them.

Comment: Good answer. Telling how to see your *uid* would also be useful.

Comment: that folder does not exist

Answer (score 6):

Ubuntu 10.10 (oneiric)

Gnome 3.2.1 Classic

Home Folder > Go > Rubbish Bin

Answer (score 5):

Explore the folder, and there you'll see the `trash` button:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On ubuntu 22.04 to recover Trash folder on Desktop, enter command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.ding show-trash true
```

To hide the icon again, run the command below to reset the key:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.ding show-trash
```