# Trash directory totally missing

Tags: directory, trash

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 with Unity. I just found that there is no Trash directory at:
`~/.local/share/Trash` like [explained](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102099/where-is-the-trash-folder) here.

Where is the Trash dir?

Comment: The directory that you say is split into three folders (*expunged* - *files* - *info*). The files that you see when open the trash are in this *files* directory.

Answer (score 3):

The directory is created once you deleted your first file.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you've got a problem, cause I've checked and it's in  `~/.local/share/Trash`.