# /boot is almost full preventing Software Updates

Tags: updates, trash

I can't do a software update because `/boot` is almost full. I, as root deleted unneeded files, but it didn't change the space problem. Trash shows that it's empty, and I can't get run `gksudo nautilus` to access roots trash to empty it. So basically, I can't do any more upgrades if they involve `/boot`.

How do I empty root's trash?

Comment: Can't you just use terminal as root to delete the files with commands?

Comment: I have tried, with no luck. Can you tell me what the command line is to empty roots trash?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
$ sudo -i
# OLDCONF=$(dpkg -l|grep "^rc"|awk '{print $2}')
# CURKERNEL=$(uname -r|sed 's/-*[a-z]//g'|sed 's/-386//g')
# LINUXPKG="linux-(image|headers|ubuntu-modules|restricted-modules)"
# METALINUXPKG="linux-(image|headers|restricted-modules)-(generic|i386|server|common|rt|xen)"
# OLDKERNELS=$(dpkg -l|awk '{print $2}'|grep -E $LINUXPKG |grep -vE $METALINUXPKG|grep -v $CURKERNEL)
# apt-get clean
# apt-get remove --purge $OLDCONF
# apt-get remove --purge $OLDKERNELS
# rm -rf /home/*/.local/share/Trash/*/** &> /dev/null
# rm -rf /root/.local/share/Trash/*/** &> /dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

`/boot` usually fills up because Ubuntu keeps old kernel versions around in case the new ones fail, so that you can go back to a working kernel. You'll need to delete old kernel versions to free up space on `/boot`.

## Automatic method

1. Reboot to ensure you're using the latest kernel version.
2. Follow [the instructions to use Ubuntu Tweak to remove old kernel versions (scroll down to the Ubuntu Tweak section)](https://askubuntu.com/a/100953/147763).

## Manual method

1. Reboot to ensure you're using the latest kernel version.
2. Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
3. Find out what kernel version you're using:

   ```
   uname -r
   ```
4. Type the following and press tab twice instead of enter:

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge linux-
   ```
5. In the output, find a kernel version other than what you're using. For example, if your kernel version is `3.19.0-22` and you see `linux-headers-3.19.0-21`, you can remove version `3.19.0-21`.
6. Remove `linux-headers-VERSION`, `linux-headers-VERSION-generic`, `linux-image-VERSION-generic`, and `linux-image-extra-VERSION-generic`. For example, if you're removing version `3.19.0-21`, run:

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge linux-headers-3.19.0-21 linux-headers-3.19.0-21-generic linux-image-3.19.0-21-generic linux-image-extra-3.19.0-21-generic
   ```
7. Go back to step 4 and repeat until you only see the kernel version you're using.

Comment: I did this and now only have the kernel I am currently using. However, I have not changed the fact that /boot drive is still mostly full. I need (I think) to somehow get the root users trash to empty, and I can't seem to.

Comment: Why do you think trash is stored in `/boot`?

Answer (score -1):

According to [this topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102099/where-is-the-trash-folder) the root's trash has to be in `/root/.local/share/Trash'

Just open a terminal and type (after `sudo -s` enter your password, no characters will be shown):

```
sudo -s
rm -rf /root/.local/share/Trash
```

It's going to delete the `Trash` folder too.

Comment: Just did that, but when I run the software update it still says I have no more room on /boot.

Comment: How big your /boot partition actually is?

Comment: The drive is 200 mb

Comment: Isn't that too small?

Comment: I would say so. its the size Ubuntu made it. Can I change the size? I have loads of space on the disk.