# Restore files moved to trash using command line

Tags: command-line, permissions, trash

How to restore a file from the trash using command line?

Obviously you can use `restore-trash` command from the `trash-cli` package, but this wouldn't list all files inside the trash.

Moreover what about files moved to trash with root permission?

Those are files in trash:
[image]

Now using `restore-trash` command:
[image]

only 4 files are shown.

Comment: Have you tried running `restore-trash` using `sudo` or checking out `sudo trash-list` are you looking for something else?

Comment: @Maythux so what was the problem? cause I can list all files (even deleted by root) without `sudo`,  and remove them using `sudo`...

Comment: Could you specify how did you delete one of the files which is not in the `sudo restore-trash` output? I guess it's related to programs behaving differently and not following the standards ...

Comment: @Ravexina command line `rm`

Comment: Shouldn't `rm` delete the file permanently ? use `trash`  or `trash-put` or `gvfs-trash` instead of `rm`.

Comment: [This trash-cli](https://github.com/andreafrancia/trash-cli) gave me `restore-trash`: `restore-trash: command not found`. As [the highest answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1166008/830570) points out, this is because is called `trash-restore` since 2019.

Answer (score 6):

If you run `trash-restore` from within a directory, It will **only** show the trashed files and directories that were trashed from **the current directory or its sub-directories**

---

As it appears, you are running `trash-restore` from your **home directory**. So, it is only showing files and directories that were trashed from your **home directory or its sub-directories**.

---

To restore files trashed from another directory, for example `/var`, you would need to `cd` to the `/var` directory first and then run `trash-restore` from there.

---

**Alternatively**, you can specify the system root directory `/` after `trash-restore` like so `trash-restore /` to make it show **all** trashed files and directories originating **from anywhere in the system**.

---

**Notice:**

The tool is called `trash-restore` since 2019 (instead of `restore-trash` previously) under the latest `trash-cli` package.

Answer (score 3):

For `listing` all files in the trash,

```
ls -l .local/share/Trash/files/

sudo ls -l /root/.local//share/Trash/files/
```

should do under Ubuntu (in my case: MATE 16.04). I [found those paths here](https://askubuntu.com/a/102106/479118). It also has further explanations of what is in the other folders next to `files/`. In case you want to code your own restore routine, that should help...

Not sure what you are up to (writing tests to verify delete-to-trash?, ...) but looking at the specific source of the [`trash npm module (js)`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/trash/blob/master/lib/linux.js) might give further insight.

---

**UPDATE:**
actually, finding the right location of a trashed file can get a whole lot more complicated, e.g. when it's not a delete from `/home/someuser/...` but other places on same partition (say `/usr/share/...`) or elsewhere (mounted drives, incl. removables...)

This should be the spec to read:
https://specifications.freedesktop.org/trash-spec/trashspec-1.0.html

The `trash` package mentioned above relies on xdg-[trashdir](https://github.com/kevva/xdg-trashdir) to find the right path.

Comment: Why is it `..../local//share/...` (with double `//`), not  `..../local/share/...` (with single `/`)? Or is that just a typo?

Answer (score 2):

Each volume has it's own trash. While `nautilus` or `nemo` shows the trash combined for all mounted volumes, `restore-trash` shows only the files from the volume you're currently in, unlike `trash-list`, which shows the trash for all mounted volumes.