# "Move to Trash" doesn't appear, but only "Delete" on context menu

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, delete, trash

I could not see "Move to Trash" option on context menu, but only seeing "Delete" option that make the file completely removed (`Are you sure you want to permanently delete “file.txt”?`). I also tried `chown/chmod` on the files and folders that I am trying to move to trash. So, I can NOT remove files via Sublime Text 3 too.

If I do `sudo nautilus` and opening the file explorer then I can see "Move to Trash" option, but then can not see the file that I moved to trash using this option in "Trash".

E.g;

```
# kerem is superuser
sudo chown kerem:kerem /var/www/file.txt
sudo chmod 0777 /var/www/file.txt
```

Trash perms;

```
kerem@kerem:~/.local/share$ ls -la | grep Trash
drwx------  5 kerem kerem  4096 Ara 11 04:09 Trash
```

[image: ubuntu-context-menu]

Using 14.04 64bit, desktop version and `/home` and `/var/www` are on different partitions like sda1 and sda7 (both ext4 `/` -> `/dev/sda6` and `/home` -> `/dev/sda7`). But no dual system alongside Ubuntu like Windows.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm assuming you're not running your file browser (eg nautilus) as superuser?  What are the permissions and ownership of your home directory and your `~/.local/share/Trash` directory?

Comment: @neon_overload; `kerem` is root, so superuser. Also updated question, thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that kerem is superuser - are you running nautilus (or whatever file browser you're using) as superuser?  If so, why?  And how - with sudo, or gksu, or some other way?

Comment: @neon_overload; I updated my question, could you see it again please?

Answer (score 2):

After wasting a few hours, here is the solution;

```
sudo -s
cd /
```

Work out your user account's id - it's usually 1000

```
getent passwd "username"
```

to get the UID and GID (for later use)

```
UID=$(getent passwd "username" | awk -F: '{print $3}')
GID=$(getent passwd "username" | awk -F: '{print $4}')
```

Make a new trash directory with the id we found above

```
mkdir .Trash-1000
```

Change the permissions of new directory to allow us to access it

```
chmod 777 .Trash-1000 && chown ${UID}:$GID .Trash-1000
```

Additionally, I can make a sym link into `~/.local/share/Trash` to remember there is a trash more, so need to be emptied sometimes. :)

```
ln -s /.Trash-1000 ~/.local/share/Trash
```

Credits: https://askubuntu.com/a/516825/179045

Comment: Specifically, the Trash folder needs to be on the same partition as the files to be deleted, so they can be moved. So if /home is a separate partition, they need to go into /home, not /

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with Gnome Files.

For all folder and files in my home dir, **Gnome Files** shows **Move to Trash** in context menu. But for files/folder in another device the context menu shows **Delete Permanently**. For example, if folder /orange is mounted on a separate partition/disk then for all files/folders under it the **Move to Trash** is not enabled.

This is because Files auto creates Trash dir under $HOME/.local/share. However as there is no Trash for /orange mount point the **Move to trash** is not enabled for /orange. To overcome this create Trash folder for each user in /orange. If uid of user foo is 1000 then create /orange/.Trash-1000 and change its owner to foo.

```
sudo mkdir /orange/.Trash-1000
sudo chown foo:foo /orange/.Trash-1000
```

Now **Move to Trash** is enabled in context menu of all files/folders under /orange.