# Enable Trash usage on external NTFS partition

Tags: partitioning, trash

So I am dual-booting Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04 with a separate ntfs partition for my music and general data. I noticed that when deleting something from this shared partition, Ubuntu tells me that the file will be deleted immediately and not sent to the trash bin. Now, that makes sense to me since it's barely different than deleting from a flashdrive. But if I were to accidentally delete something, I would like a way to easily recover it. So, does anyone know if/how you can create some sort of trash bin on this shared partition (i.e. if I delete a song on the partition while running Ubuntu it will go to a trash folder on the partition, and if I delete a song while running Windows it will also go to that trash folder).
I'm sure someone must have a solution, or at least advice on what they do to avoid deleting anything by mistake. Thanks in advance for any help.

Edit: Sorry for the "off topic" thing with Windows. How I should have worded it is 'Is there a way to create a trash bin that is actually located on the shared partition?'

Comment: Regarding Ubuntu: you need to mount it with the user id of your user. http://askubuntu.com/questions/75154/cannot-move-file-to-trash-warning-when-trying-to-delete-a-file-in-nautilus and http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1499345 "and if I delete a song while running Windows it will also go to that trash folder" Windows ... off topic ;)

Comment: Thanks for the links, I think they might help me get something worked out (although with a different outcome than I originally was intending).

Comment: If this can not be solved: In Linux you could always alias "rm" to do a "mv" to a trash location.