# Files from mounted volume cannot be send to trash, only deleted permanently

Tags: mount, delete, trash

I use Ubuntu 18.04.3 on the laptop with two logical volumes. When I select some file on the home volume and press "Del", it goes to Trash. On the mounted volume when I press "Del" it is removed permanently. If I do the right click on the file I also see only "Delete permanently" option.

It did not work like this before, and I am not sure what changed, because I think that I did not install any updates in the time period when the behavior changed.

The folder ".Trash-1000" on the mounted volume still exists.

Any idea how to turn on the "Delete to trash" option again?

UPD: About the size of the file: I am experimenting now with a 5 kb txt file.

Comment: Some files can be too large for the Trash. Please click [edit] and advise the size of the files you wish to put in Trash.

Comment: Done. Checked it first thing.

Comment: To be considered a usable trashbin, '1000' should be your UID, and the folder should have the sticky bit (`t` bit) set.

Comment: After some search the recipe from here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/75154/cannot-move-file-to-trash-warning-when-trying-to-delete-a-file-in-nautilus/516825#516825 helped.