# Nautilus: Undo delete using Ctrl+z not working

Tags: 18.04, nautilus

When I accidentally delete a file in nautilus by pressing delete I normally can press Ctrl+z immediately afterwards to undo the action.

However, this seems to only work in my home directory. Whenever I work on a mounted partition I cannot "undo" a delete action.

How to fix this?

Comment: This may depend whether Trash is enabled on that filesystem. Does your problem seems similar to this? https://askubuntu.com/questions/75154/cannot-move-file-to-trash-warning-when-trying-to-delete-a-file-in-nautilus

Comment: The accepted answer looks a bit evolved and rather suited for NTFS partitions.
I guess setting the `uid=1000` option during the mount command in my `/etc/fstab` might do the trick, currently it is mounted like this: `/dev/sda1 /media/data ext4 defaults 0 0`
I will try this, once the partition is not in use anymore

Comment: where I would replace `defaults` with `rw,suid,dev,exec,auto,user,async` according to https://wiki.debian.org/fstab

Comment: FYI: Trash is working now on /media/data (mounted partition)